# Projection onto finite-dimensional subspace of $L^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $a_i$ be a basis of $L^p(\Omega)$ and consider $A_n = \text{span}\{a_1, ..., a_n\}$.

Take an element $f \in L^p$. We want to define a projection onto the finite-dimensional subspace $A_n$. How do we define this? we do not have an inner product available to us.

How about this. Let $B_n = \text{span}\{b_1, ..., b_n\}$ where $b_i$ is a basis of $L^q$ ($p$ and $q$ conjugate). Then define $P_n:L^p \to L^q$ by
$$P_n f = \sum_{i=1}^n\langle f, b_i \rangle_{L^p, L^q}b_i$$.

However this is in $L^q$.

What's the natural projection operator on Banach spaces? The context is **Galerkin approximations to PDEs** so nothing too abstract please. What's the link to the dual space? In the Hilbert space setting, the projection operator satisfies $(P_n h, h_n) = (h, h_n)$, does something similar hold here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the natural projection operator on Banach spaces?

There isn't one natural  projection onto a given subspace. However, since you already made a choice of Schauder basis $a_i$, there is a natural choice of projection onto your spaces $A_n$. Indeed, every element $x\in L^p$ expands uniquely as $\sum c_i a_i$. Define
$$P_nx = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i a_i$$

Fortunately, the norms of projections $P_n$ are [uniformly bounded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis).

By definition, a basis is called *monotone* if $\|P_n\|=1$ for all $n$; these are the nicest bases to have. The Haar system is a monotone basis for $L^p$, $1<p<\infty$. For an investigation of such bases, see [Monotone bases in $L_p$](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102868433) by Dor and Odell.

In general, finding the coefficients $c_i$ may be hard. But for Haar system you can use the fact that it's orthonormal in $L^2$, and use the inner product of $L^2$ to find $c_i$.

---

Aside: in a uniformly convex space such as $L^p$, $1<p<\infty$, there is a well-defined *nearest point projection* onto any closed subspace. However, this is a *nonlinear* operator, which is unlikely to be suitable for your purpose.